# javascript capture all listbox values for php

Tags: php, javascript, listbox, capture

I have a page that lets people assign items to a category and javascript that lets user move as many items as desired from one box on left to one on right and back so that users can preview and fine tune choices (which end up in right box).  It might be better if the items could be moved between lists instead of listboxes, but select box, I guess, is good for selecting uponclick.  When user is done, I need to post items in right box to php script.  However, am having trouble figuring out how to capture all the items in the right list.  There is no form in the script so can't get it from document.form.  Items are not really selected, they just populate list and I want to get them all.  Is there a variable that has the whole list?  Script is lengthy so here are functions that do work. Essentially I need a way to write out list of elements in right box at end.  Thanks for any suggestions.

```
   function moveToRightOrLeft(side) {
    var listLeft = document.getElementById('selectLeft');
    var listRight = document.getElementById('selectRight');
    if (side == 1) {
        if (listLeft.options.length == 0) {
            alert('You have already assigned all items to the category');
            return false;
        } else {
            var selectedItem = listLeft.options.selectedIndex;
            move(listRight, listLeft.options[selectedItem].value, listLeft.options[selectedItem].text);
            listLeft.remove(selectedItem);
            if (listLeft.options.length > 0) {
                listLeft.options[0].selected = true;
            }
        }
    } else if (side == 2) {
        if (listRight.options.length == 0) {
            alert('The list is empty');
            return false;
        } else {
            var selectedItem = listRight.options.selectedIndex;
            move(listLeft, listRight.options[selectedItem].value, listRight.options[selectedItem].text);
            listRight.remove(selectedItem);
            if (listRight.options.length > 0) {
                listRight.options[0].selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

function move(listBoxTo, optionValue, optionDisplayText) {
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = optionValue;
    newOption.text = optionDisplayText;
    listBoxTo.add(newOption, null);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @DenisErmolin It takes two seconds to edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think you have an error in your syntax. To get the value of the selected item of a select box, you would use something like:

```
var value = listLeft.options[listLeft.selectedIndex].value;
```

To write out all the options in a particular select box, you should be able to do something like this:

```
var options = document.getElementById('selectRight').options;
for (i=0; i<options.length(); i++)
    document.write("value "+ i +" = "+ options[i].value);
```

---

I reworked your code a tiny bit and here is a complete working example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        select
        {
            width:100px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/Javascript">
        function moveToRightOrLeft(side)
        {
            if (side == 1)
            {
                var list1 = document.getElementById('selectLeft');
                var list2 = document.getElementById('selectRight');
            }
            else
            {
                var list1 = document.getElementById('selectRight');
                var list2 = document.getElementById('selectLeft');
            }

            if (list1.options.length == 0)
            {
                alert('The list is empty');
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                var selectedItem = list1.options[list1.selectedIndex];
                move(list2, selectedItem.value, selectedItem.text);
                list1.remove(list1.selectedIndex);
                if (list1.options.length > 0)
                    list1.options[0].selected = true;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function move(listBoxTo, optionValue, optionDisplayText)
        {
            var newOption = document.createElement("option");
            newOption.value = optionValue;
            newOption.text = optionDisplayText;
            listBoxTo.add(newOption, null);
            return true;
        }

        function showContents(listBoxID)
        {
            var options = document.getElementById(listBoxID).options;
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
                alert("Option "+ options[i].value +" = "+ options[i].text);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="selectLeft" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="2">Value 2</option>
        <option value="3">Value 3</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="moveToRightOrLeft(2)">&lt;</button>
    <button onclick="moveToRightOrLeft(1)">&gt;</button>
    <select id="selectRight" multiple="multiple">
    </select>
    <button onclick="showContents('selectRight')">Show Contents</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that did not work of itself.  Can you suggest syntax to document.write a single value based on variables in script. Perhaps I can get it from there.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're having trouble with. If you copy and paste the above example into a new HTML page, then it works fine. Doing `var options = document.getElementById('selectRight').options;` will place all of the options in the `selectRight` box into an array called `options`. Then you can loop through them (with a for-loop...like I did) and do whatever you want with them...`document.write(options[i].text);`, `document.write(options[i].value);`, or whatever you want to do with them. What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I must have sent my comment before refreshing to see yours! It probably didn't work for me as I did not include a handler to fire the alert/document.write etc.  Many thanks!

Comment: One last question if you don't mind.  Can the array be natively posted as in document.write('<input type="hidden" name="data" value="'+options+'">')?  In that case, could I place <form="post.php" method="post" id="myform"><input type = hidden...>></form> in the showcontents function?

Comment: Strike last question.  Figured out how to send as array.